# Error al enviar un JSON.stringify por medio de un evento onclick en javaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

deseo enviar un array asociativo por medio de un evento `onclick`, al enviarlo cuando lo capturo me aparece `[object object]` entonces intente enviarlo de tipo `string` utilizando `JSON.stringify()` lo hago de la siguiente manera:

Evento onclick

```
$('#div').html('<div class="col-xs-6 text-center"><a href="#" class="on-primary edit-row" onclick=\' mostrarDatos("'+JSON.stringify(datos)+'"); \'><i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></div>');
```

Asi se muestra cuando capturo el error en la consola

```
mostrarDatos("[{"id":"1","nombre":"Prueba","direccion":"calle 2 av Siemprevivas","telefono":"123332123","observaciones":"Asdasdasdasdas","correo":"123@gmail.com","fechaInicio":"2016-07-01","fechaFin":"2017-02-08","logo":"archivos/mpg.jpg","costo":"9","estado":"1","Municipio_id":"1259","Estado_id":"777","Empresa_id":"2","municipio":"Cali"}]");
```

Este es el error que me muestra en la consola
[image: error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error es que estás poniendo comillas dobles dentro de una cadena delimitada con comillas dobles, entonces eso hace que la cadena se rompa y dé errores. Se puede ver que está mal hasta en la coloración que StackOverflow le da al código:

```
mostrarDatos("[{"id":"1","nombre":"Prueba","direccion":"calle 2 av Siemprevivas","telefono":"123332123","observaciones":"Asdasdasdasdas","correo":"123@gmail.com","fechaInicio":"2016-07-01","fechaFin":"2017-02-08","logo":"archivos/mpg.jpg","costo":"9","estado":"1","Municipio_id":"1259","Estado_id":"777","Empresa_id":"2","municipio":"Cali"}]");
```

Un método sencillo sería cambiar la comilla doble de fuera por una simple. Entonces ya funcionará todo bien (y se colorea bien):

```
mostrarDatos('[{"id":"1","nombre":"Prueba","direccion":"calle 2 av Siemprevivas","telefono":"123332123","observaciones":"Asdasdasdasdas","correo":"123@gmail.com","fechaInicio":"2016-07-01","fechaFin":"2017-02-08","logo":"archivos/mpg.jpg","costo":"9","estado":"1","Municipio_id":"1259","Estado_id":"777","Empresa_id":"2","municipio":"Cali"}]');
```

Pero eso requeriría cambiar mucho la cadena original. Es más sencillo escapar las comillas el resultado de cJSON.stringify de la siguiente manera:

```
JSON.stringify(datos).replace(/\"/g,"&quot;")
```

Aquí te dejo un ejemplo simplificado que funciona usando ese método:

```js
function mostrarDatos(a) { alert(JSON.stringify(a))}

datos = [{"id":"1","nombre":"Prueba"}];
$('#div').html('<div class="col-xs-6 text-center"><a href="#" class="on-primary edit-row" onclick=\' mostrarDatos('+JSON.stringify(datos).replace(/\"/g,"&quot;")+'); \'><i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i>AAAA</a></div>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div">
</div>
```

Comment: Gracias si tenia conocimiento que era algo relacionado con las comillas pero no sabia como hacerlo, como decias elimine las comillas dobles y el error se soluciono  `$('#div').html('<div class="col-xs-6 text-center"><a href="#" class="on-primary edit-row" onclick=\' mostrarDatos('+JSON.stringify(datos)+'); \'><i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></div>');` , era algo simple pero me tenia dando vueltas, de nuevo muchas gracias

Comment: He puesto otra alternativa que creo que hubiera requerido menos cambios